# getch(); runtime error in c and codeblock

Tags: c, gcc, codeblocks, getch

I use codeblocks IDE and gcc compiler. I tried to write the simple program billing system.We I use the getch(); for character input there will be no error during building the project but at run time there will be error and shows the error message like this "Drawing operation was attempted when there was no current window."
What was the actual problem.

Comment: Are you mixing BGI graphics with all of this? You need to explain a your code little more.

Comment: Iam not mixing BGI graphics just console application

Comment: Please post some code that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are using in windows with Code::Blocks with gcc I'm safely assumeing you are using cygwin toolchain, which is a linux like environment. So I recomend you to use `system("pause")` including the header `stdlib.h`

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned in what platform you are compiling. If it's Linux you can not use `getch()` since `conio.h` is only for dos. But with this error message is most probably caused by incorrect integration of gcc with Code::Blocks. Try compling with gcc directly.

Comment: Iam compiling in windows platform.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("this is getch");
    getch();
    return 0;
} This simple program also doesn't work